Is there any phonetic approach to distinguish sʲa v.s. sia?
I'm working on a language where there are syllables sound like /sʲa, ʃʲa, θʲa/ or maybe /sia, ʃia, θia/ etc. I want to conduct an experiment determining whether there are palatalized consonants or not. Either acoustic analysis or articulatory analysis (ultrasound, EMA, etc.) is OK to me. I wonder whether there're such kind of research and how did they do this?
Any papers or suggestions?

If you are inventing it, why don't you just decide what you want? Or are you saying you don't know how they would sound uttered in those two ways?

@Lambie Thanks for correcting my English. Edited. And, as for this question, yes, if there isn't such a method, I'd like to invent one (maybe F1/F2 transitions, HNR, or some articulatory similarities with /i/, I guess). I've done some searches and found nothing in the literature. I'm asking this for some suggestions on this topic and also for any papers I've missed.

There's no way to definitively answer this on phonetic grounds alone. The Handbook of the IPA addresses the question on pp. 33–34. It says, "There may be some evidence in the phonetic signal to help resolve the issue", e.g. whether there is a "noticeable [i]-like transition" during the approach phase of the consonant just like during the release. "But ultimately the answer will lie in the phonological patterns of the language", and it says it would be one reason to treat it as [Cj] if the language had /j/ as an onset, and as [Cʲ] if it "contrasted consonants extensively in terms of secondary articulation" like /asʲ/ vs /asʷ/.

Uhm, but unless it's a small mistake, they're asking about /ʲ/ vs /i/, not vs /j/...

@LjL - "there are palatalized consonants" may sound like a purely physiological question, i.e., like "are certain consonants ever articulated close to the palate", but the standard meaning of that phrase is actually phonological, such as "does the presence or absence of palatalization play any systematic role in how that language communicates meanings".  That is a very general terminological remark to grasp early enough in any research and as such it doesn't heavily depend on what the exact phonological feature and/or sounds involved are.
